# Series and integral transforms in Python

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, special-functions, python

Let $z$ be a complex element in the unit disc. Let's consider an integral transform from $0$ to $\infty$ denoted by $R_{n,m}(f)(z)$ with two fixed parameters $n$ and $m$ where $f$ is a square integrable function on $\mathbb{R^+}$.

I wish to draw graph in $3D$ in general for $n=0,m=0$ and $n=1,m=0$ and $n=0,m=1$ and $n=1,m=1$ and $n=1,m=2$ and $n=2,m=1$ and $n=2,m=2$ and $n=2,m=3$ and $n=3,m=2$ and $n=3,m=3$.

**For example**

- Image for Bessel functions
  [image]
- Image Generalized Laguerre polynomials
  [image]

Same problem for infinite series, I have tried the following program just for $m=1$ and $n=1$ but it showed an error.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sym
import math
import numpy as np

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x=np.linespace(0.0,0.5,20)
y=np.linespace(0.0,0.5,20)

n=1
m=1
z=complex(x,y)

def zero_to_infinity():
    i = 0

    while True:
        yield i
        i += 1

def CalcMYSeries(x,y):
    res, temp = 0, 0
    for i in zero_to_infinity():
        res += ((math.gamma(i+n+m))*((z)**i) )
        if res == temp:
            break
        temp = res
    return res

f=CalcMYSeries(x,y)

X, Y= np.meshgrid(x, y)

F=f(X,Y)

fig=plt.figure(figsize=[12,8])
ax = fig.gca(projection = '3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, F, cmap=cm.coolwarm)

plt.show()
```

I have tried this many times but it didn't work. How to plot this series $K_{n,m}(z)$ for $z$ in the complex unit disc? Moreover, how to write modified Bessel function in python?

Comment: Image descriptions are here:

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbCsK.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7R8c.png

Comment: You should format your code so that someone who wants to try it out can just cut & paste. See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks.

Comment: `zero_to_infinity()` is equivalent to `itertools.count()`, [which can be passed optional arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) for its start & step size.